# Swapping Screens in Android with Button Click

Tags: android, button, android-activity, screen, swap

i try to make 2 screen activities in Android, and a button on each one, when you click the button to go to the other screen.

I have made everything like in this tutorial: [Watch It here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sLd1S6kQ7n8)

But, if i remove following code from AndroidManifest.xml

```
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

the app doesnt install on any android device.
If I leave the AndroidManifest,  the app installs and it works, but only the second screen :(.

Help me please, explain me why, and how it must need to work.

Thank You!

Comment: Is the above `manifest` code only in your second `Activity` tag?

Comment: Did you declare all the Activities of your application in manifest ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any Android app to work there should be a main launcher activity ( just link in a standalone java app a main() function is required )

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.example.androidswitchviews"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0">
  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name=".FirstScreenActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <!-- Add new Activity class name here --->
    <activity android:name=".SecondScreen"></activity>

</application>
```

Follow tutorial link :- 
http://www.androidhive.info/2011/08/how-to-switch-between-activities-in-android/

Comment: here is mine: 
   
`<activity
android:name=".BasicScreenActivity"
android:label="@string/app_name" >
</activity>
<activity
android:name="OtherScreenActivity"
android:label="@string/title_activity_other_screen" >
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
</activity>
</application>
</manifest>`

Comment: in your case "OtherScreenActivity" becomes main activity

Comment: as I understood from tutorial, if I remove: 
`<intent-filter> </intent-filter>`
the app should work, with 2 acitivity screens. But it doesnt even install. 

If I leave intent filter, it works but only with 1 activity screen.

Comment: Hi Guys! Resolved the problem:  Just replaced in the AndroidManifest.xml the Activities: First Must Be The 2nd screen.  `<activity
android:name="OtherScreenActivity"
android:label="@string/title_activity_other_screen" >
</activity>
<activity
android:name=".BasicScreenActivity"
android:label="@string/app_name" >
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
</activity>`